# Dynamically Edit Inline CSS with VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

How can I change an attribute of a tag with VueJS? I'm trying to make a one-page app with a background that changes every time it fetches data from a backend. I've tried using the `v-bind:style` and `v-style` but both ended up "breaking" Vue. Is there a way I can just write a method like you can in native JS that changes the DOM? I also tried implementing a `document.getElementbyId` so and and so forth but it also wrecked VueJS.

In other words, how can I do background-image: {{pic_url}};

Sorry for formatting, on mobile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had some trouble getting this working because there are quotes around the inline style, then two more sets of quotes in `'url("")'`.  When I pulled the style object out into its own object I got it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/ahwLc3rq/

**html**

```
<div id="app">
  <div id="test" :style="backgroundStyle"></div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
new Vue({
    el:'#app',
  data:function(){
    return {
        pic_url: 'https://anchormetrics.com/wp-content/themes/bootstrap-basic-child/images/amlogo.png'
    }
  },
  computed:{
   backgroundStyle:function(){
    return {
        'background-image':'url("'+this.pic_url+'")'
    }
   }
  },
  methods:{
    fetchPic:function(){
      this.$http.get('/path/to/api').then(function(response){
        this.pic_url = response;
      }.bind(this))
    }
  },
  ready:function(){
    this.fetchPic();
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok so two question: Why `:style` instead of `v-style`, and why `computed` instead of `methods`?

Comment: And also, how do I change `pic_url` since it is within the function? `pic_url` isn't known at first as it's acquired through a GET request.

Comment: `:style` is shorthand for `v-bind:style` and I think `v-style` is deprecated.  As for computed, computed properties are just like data properties except they re-compute anytime a property they use is changed.  So when `pic_url` changes, `backgroundStyle` will automatically update

Comment: As for that, just set `pic_url:""` in your data function and then when you retrieve it you can update it and `backgroundStyle` will re-compute.

Comment: So in the http request function would I just add `this.$set('pic_url', result);`?

Comment: I'm a complete newb to web dev and JS (I hail from Ruby), so I'm not sure what the unnamed function is supposed to do... is it essentially an implicit block?

Comment: the data function is just supposed to return the initial data of the vue component. I updated with an example http request.  by adding `.bind(this)` to the function you make sure that `this` in the callback still refers to vue, allowing you to set `this.pic_url`

Comment: Ok one last question... what is`.bind()`?

Comment: see last comment for that :) normally in a callback function, `this` is no longer in the scope of the original component.

Comment: Oh sorry... didn't see that last comment. Thanks, I'll go try this out.

Comment: Oh man thank you dude, finally got it working when I changed the `:style` to `v-style`. I was probably doing something wrong with your solution, but it works now. +1 for sticking with me